# Using URL rewrite to access menu item on a static site?

Tags: javascript, html, mod-rewrite

First off, I'm not using a CMS or PHP. This site is more-or-less static, and has a top-level index.html.

My problem is that some users have to go through multiple steps to get to a particular menu item which displays a form, and I'd like to give them a URL to do this directly, and to fill in some of the boxes for them.

The page that's currently loaded by *manually* going to this menu item directly has no specific URL. Normally, when the user clicks through on the top-level menu, some JS simply displays the relevant form, so the user is still at `http://www.foo.com`, for example (in fact, the whole site is at the top-level URL, with lots of JavaScript and Ajax doing everything). This means that I can't use a simple rewrite rule to display the menu, and that wouldn't fill in any parts of the form anyway.

Any ideas on how to do this? The only option I can think of at the moment is:

1. User clicks on a new URL like `foo.com/forms/optionN`
2. Apache redirects this to a script (actually C++) which processes the `optionN`, and which then returns an entire modified version of `index.html`, with the menu item showing the form filled in according to `optionN`

This sounds like a bad idea. What I'd really like to do is to send the user to the unmodified `foo.com/index.html`, and then for the server to return some JS which opens up the menu item and fills in the fields. I suppose I could instead embed some JS in an otherwise unmodified `index.html`.

Any ideas how to do this properly? how would a CMS like Joomla or WordPress do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is your option (2), which is pretty much what a CMS would be doing for you - parsing the HTTP/GET QUERY_STRING, and generating content specific to the QUERY_STRING.

If you can't do this and want to keep your HTML static, then this should work, but isn't perfect.

First, your HTML/JS needs to understand `foo.com?path1=forms&path2=optionN`.

This is easy - the JavaScript must read `window.location` and parse it. There's an example [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html). You can then use the values of `path1` and `path2` to open your menus, or whatever.

Second, you have to arrange for the server to turn `foo.com/forms/optionN/` into `foo.com?path1=forms&path2=optionN`, *and return it to the client*. This is harder than it looks, because a rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/?path2=$2&path3=$3
```

is only visible to the *server*. If you do this, the client will still think it's at `foo.com/forms/optionN/`, and that's what you'll find in `window.location`, which is no good. To get around this you have to do a redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/?path2=$2&path3=$3 [R]
```

The server now explicitly sends a redirect back to the client, and the client then does a GET with the correct URI (`foo.com?path1=forms&path2=optionN`), and the client sees the 'correct' `window.location`. Unfortunately, the client's address bar also changes to show the redirect URI, which isn't great, but at least it works.

You'll have to modify `RewriteRule` for your setup - the path that gets substituted depends on your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, and whether you do this in `.htaccess` or the config file, and so on.